# Thailand to St Martens (West Indies)

Tags: visas, schengen, transit

I am looking at the travel arrangements for flights from Bangkok to St Martens as the individual will be working in the British Virgin Islands. She has her visa to work and will be requiring a flight at the end of September.

The most economical way of getting her to St Martens is via Miami but because of the visa restrictions this is not an option as she has not applied for a US visa. The next option is via either Amsterdam or London. The latter is an option as she will have a BV visa. Would she need a visa just to transfer through Amsterdam?

Comment: Er, what's the citizenship in question? Thai?

Comment: Yes she is a Thai national going to work in the British Virgin Islands (lucky girl). She has a visa which will allow her freely to enter the islands or the UK for that matter. Its obviously a long way so the best cost / transit time option is via the USA but they have visa restrictions for transit people. The Euro zone has the Schengen agreement so we were hoping that a simple connection without the need for visa's will be.

Comment: All the rules, sources, etc. are detailed in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area but, briefly, a Thai national does not need any visa to change planes while remaining airside in either Amsterdam or Paris.

Comment: But, if I understand you correctly, she would first fly to the Dutch part of the island of Saint Martin? Since you are not asking about that, I assume you have got that covered but she might need a visa there. While Saint Martin is shared between the Netherlands and France, it's not part of the Schengen area and each territory has its own visa system.

Comment: Related http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56223/how-can-an-indian-citizen-travel-to-trinidad-and-tobago-from-india-without-needi

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK St. Maarten isn't served from London. It is served from Amsterdam and Paris, so you'll need to change planes in either of those locations. Best is to check with a consulate or embassy (given that both the Netherlands and France are Schengen signatories the rules should be fairly similar).
When choosing between the two, Amsterdam is probably the best option as the airport is far better suited to transfer passengers as compared to Paris (or London for that matter).

Comment: -1 This answer basically reformulates the question without actually answering it.

Answer (score 1):

Flying from London/Gatwick to Antigua is another option. A connecting flight to BVI can be booked with VI Airlink viairlink.com which has direct flights for passengers on Virgin Atlantic and British Airways on Fridays & Saturdays. LIAT, the regional airline, also has connecting flights to Tortola www.liat.com

In transit passengers traveling within the same day (24 hours), who normally require a visa, do not need a visa for entry into Antigua and Barbuda, provided that they have proof of their onward journey. Should an Antiguan transit visa be required, it can be arranged via the British consulate in Thailand (only in countries where Antigua & Barbuda does not have an embassy or consulate).