# How can an Indian citizen travel to Trinidad and Tobago from India without needing a transit visa along the way?

Tags: air-travel, india, indian-citizens, transit-visas, trinidad-and-tobago

I would like to travel to Port of Spain (Trinidad and Tobago) from India. Can anyone help me to find the route (or routes) to avoid getting a transit visa?

Comment: I think your best option is to apply for a visa from the USA. It is possible to obtain a transit visa even if you have been refused a tourist/business visa.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from the destination, Trinidad and Tobago has [two airports with commercial services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Trinidad_and_Tobago). Unfortunately, all the long-haul or transcontinental flights listed in the Wikipedia articles on [Piarco International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piarco_International_Airport) and [A.N.R. Robinson Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Napoleon_Raymond_Robinson_International_Airport) go to countries where Indian citizens do need visas for transit (including the US, the UK, Canada and Germany) so there is no obvious solution here.

A route through another country in the Caribbean might work but I could not find any viable option, in particular because Indian citizens apparently need a visa in Suriname and in Saint-Martin/Sint-Marteen, both of which are served directly from Amsterdam Schiphol, where you could transit without visa.

Note that if you have a residence permit or visa for the US, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, Japan or a country in the EU, you might qualify for an exemption, e.g. in London or Frankfurt.

Comment: Emirates fly to Panama City, and Copa flies from there to Trinidad. Might that work as a routing? Do Indian citizens need transit visas in Panama?

Comment: @Gagravarr Playing a bit with the IATA travel centre website, I think a visa would be required in Panama but it's difficult to find definitive information on that.

Comment: [This website which google suggested](http://www.worldtravelguide.net/panama/passport-visa) indicates no transit visa is required if you stay airside for less than 9 hours, not sure if you can find anything official to back that up?

Comment: @Gagravarr It doesn't appear to be possible to get that routing on a single booking. At least not for mere mortals. That means a landside transit, if you haven't got a miracle worker for a travel agent.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It may be that a basic website won't offer it, but [Cope is an Emirates interline partner](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/baggage/baggage-allowances-rules-interline-partners.aspx) so it's possible to put the two flights on one booking with baggage checked through. Probably try a "bricks and mortar" travel agent rather than a rubbish website!

Comment: @Gagravarr Emirates.com is a rubbish website? :)

Comment: Most likely! They'll probably only want to sell you their own flights, not anything complicated involving interlining and unusual destinations. Go find a real travel agent! :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer to [How can an Indian citizen travel to Ecuador without a transit visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115261/how-can-an-indian-citizen-travel-to-ecuador-on-arrival-visa-from-india-without-n), it looks like you can do this by going India -> Amsterdam -> Paramaribo -> Trinidad and Tobago.

- Amsterdam doesn't require an airport transit visa for Indian citizens changing planes when both flights are outside the Schengen area. (See: [Netherlands Airport Transit Visa](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/airport-transit-visa))
- Paramaribo allows Indian citizens to get a tourist card at the airport ("visa on arrival"). (See: [Wikipedia: Visa policy of Suriname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Suriname))